# Violation of IID in Peaks over Threshold

Tags: extreme-value, threshold

I'm using the peaks over threshold method to answer a researchquestion. I'm working with time-series data and the observations are not entirely independent. I know that there is some methods you could apply to make the observations approximately independent as "declustering-method", however my data is quite small which, as for my understandning, leaving not to many observations to fit a Generalized pareto distribution.

My question is - how much of a problem are violation of the IID assumption causing in POT-method? It will probably cause some bias to the results but is it a huge problem?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is - how much of a problem are violation of the IID assumption causing in POT-method?

It's hard to say, as this depends on the data. If the data is stationary, and the exceedences occur far apart, then probably not much. If all the exceedences occur in the same place then this would be more of a problem

Is it possible to simulate more similar data, for which you know the true distribution? If so then you could use this to quantify the modelling error

You say the time series is not iid, is it alternatively possible to fit a model to the data so the residuals look iid? That way you could perform POT on the residuals

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the data is stationary, and the exceedances do not occur on the same place. Does the violation of IID mean that I will take too extreme values if they occur on the same place? My two most extreme values in the dataset are followed by eachother, if I would use "declustering-method" to get IID, I would probably just use the most extreme value of them? So when I violate the assumption, I use too extreme values? Is that possible? Hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Since your data is stationary, and exceedances are generally not close, have you tried testing for white noise (e.g. Ljung-Box)? Depending on the outcome, an iid assumption may yet be reasonable. If you are still worried, you could fit several models by bootstrapping/subsampling your data, this would give you an idea of how much uncertainty there is in your model